# axios remove / before get request

Tags: reactjs, redux, get, axios

I am using

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?`,
  responseType: "json",
});
```

and then the response appends this to the request

```
const res = await weatherApi.get(
    `lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${KEY}&units=${unit}`
  );
```

but the end result is 
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?/lat=53&lon=1.15&appid=keyremoved&units=metric

after the `onecall?` axios inserts `/`, is there a way to disable this? It is breaking my request.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/757#issuecomment-291016487

You can use axios interceptors for this, but be weary this will modify all your requests, you might want to use more careful checks for when to do this!

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (config.url[config.url.length - 1] === '/') {
    config.url = config.url.substr(0, str.length - 1);
  }
  return config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params using params option inside get.

```
const res = await weatherApi.get({
  params: {
     lat: lat,
     lon: lon,
     appid: KEY,
     units: unit
  }
);
```

axios get request can handle params easily.

and also remove `?` from your base url.